# How to install perl-POE-Component-Jabber 2.02

Tags: perl, poe

I'm using SL6 and I need to install [perl-POE-Component-Jabber](https://metacpan.org/pod/POE::Component::Jabber) [v2.02](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/NPEREZ/POE-Component-Jabber-2.02/lib/POE/Component/Jabber.pm) with yum but I can not find this package in any repository for SL6. Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 0):

[MetaCPAN](https://metacpan.org/) links to it. Go to the project [page](https://metacpan.org/pod/POE::Component::Jabber). On the left, select the Jump to version dropdown and select 2.02 from the BackPAN section. When that version's [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/NPEREZ/POE-Component-Jabber-2.02/lib/POE/Component/Jabber.pm) loads, click the [Download](https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/N/NP/NPEREZ/POE-Component-Jabber-2.02.tar.gz) link on the left to get the tgz. Install it. (You may want to use [App::cpanminus](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::cpanminus) to simplify installation.)

Comment: Thanks! But I have tried to download that file but I can't resolve all of the dependencies. I want to use yum, is this possible?